# How to draw path with alternating colors

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I want to draw a path where edges have alternating colors, like:

[image]

Ideally I want to use

```
\draw[red] (3,0)-- (3.5,0.5) -- (4,0.2) -- (4,-0.2) -- (3.5,-0.5) -- cycle;
```

But this can only specify a single color for the entire path. The best I can do is to use \path below then I need to repeat every coordinate twice, which is very awkward. I was wondering

(a) if this can accomplished in the style \draw + cycle as above by specifying the color of each edge along the way.

(b) if somehow the operation of alternating color can be automated, that would be even better!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
(3,0) edge[blue] (3.5,0.5)
(3.5,0.5) edge[red] (4,0.2)
(4,0.2) edge[blue] (4,-0.2)
(4,-0.2) edge[red] (3.5,-0.5)
(3.5,-0.5) edge[blue] (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what is missing in your solution?

Comment: does `\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every edge/.append style = {draw=blue, line cap=round}]
\path
(3,0)       edge        (3.5,0.5)
(3.5,0.5)   edge[red]   (4,0.2)
(4,0.2)     edge        (4,-0.2)
(4,-0.2)    edge[red]   (3.5,-0.5)
(3.5,-0.5)  edge        (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document} 
` gives what you looking for?

Comment: Thanks @Zarko. Your solution sets the default color to blue, which is nice. I was wondering if it is possible to somehow avoid writing every coordinate TWICE.

Comment: using edges no. however, if your drawing present regular polygon, that you  you can draw polygon blue and overwrite only red edges.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use "append after command" to automatically repeat the coordinate. When you use `edge` tikz stores the target in `\tikztotarget`, but this is in a local scope. By the time the "append after command" code is executed, the most recent coordinate has been forgotten. So the `every edge` code has to store the current value of `\tikztotarget` in a global variable, using `\global\let\currenttarget\tikztotarget`. Then we can append this using `append after command`.

In order to automatically alternate color, we use the standard tex "command that alternates between doing two things" pattern, but again because of scope issues you have to remember to do a global assignment.

For reference the relevant command is `\tikz@do@edge` which is defined on line 2912 of tikz.code.tex. The edge is drawn on line 2932 and our edge style code is evaluated there, the `append after command` code gets locally stored in `\tikz@after@path` and is globally put into `\tikz@after@path@smuggle` on line 2933. The scope then ends and the `\tikz@after@path@smuggle` code is evaluated on line 2949.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\alternatecolorred{%
    \pgfkeysalso{red}%
    \global\let\alternatecolor\alternatecolorblue % next time make it blue
}
\def\alternatecolorblue{%
    \pgfkeysalso{blue}%
    \global\let\alternatecolor\alternatecolorred % next time make it red
}
\let\alternatecolor\alternatecolorred % first coordinate is red
\begin{tikzpicture}[every edge/.append code = {%
    \global\let\currenttarget\tikztotarget % save \tikztotarget in a global variable
    \pgfkeysalso{append after command={(\currenttarget)}}% automatically repeat it
    \alternatecolor
}]

\draw (3,0) edge (3.5,0.5) edge (4,0.2) edge (4,-0.2) edge (3.5,-0.5) edge (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```