# Curved line with varying style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Following [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51546/tikz-multi-segment-line-of-varying-thickness?noredirect=1&lq=1), I was wondering if it is possible to draw (with a single `\draw` call) a curved line that is partially of one style then of another etc ...

A solution proposed in the linked post works for straight lines. But when adding `in = ..., out=...` options to the `to` paths, the style goes back to the default, which is not really surprising.

I already tried with `append after command` to see it I could append the style but it doesn't seem to work.

Basically, the idea would be to alter the styles to support other options but I am not comfortable enough with this to see what to do.

Thanks for the help!

The MWE below, taken from @AlainMatthes answer reproduces the missing styles.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{%
xultra thick/.style={to path={%
\pgfextra{%
 \draw[line cap=round, line join=round,ultra thick]
      (\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget);} (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
xthin/.style={to path={%
\pgfextra{%
 \draw[line cap=round, line join=round,thin] 
       (\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget);} (\tikztotarget)  \tikztonodes}}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0.25,0) -- (0.75,1.2) -- (1.25,1.5) 
  to[xultra thick,in=70,out=50]  (1.75,0.7) -- (2.25,1.1) -- (2.75,0.5)
                 -- (3.25,1.5) to[xthin,in=50,out=80] (4.25,1.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that we have sort of agreed that it is not necessarily a good idea to work with `\pgfextra` and glad to see you consider using edges. One way to avoid the need to double the coordinates has been proposed in [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396092/121799), which is interesting on its own.

A common problem of many of these proposals is, however, that they tend to destroy the paths. That is, you can no longer use the path to define a boundary that can be filled, or use the path in intersections and so on. Here is a way to avoid this problem, building on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396092/121799). Look at the MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{intersections} % only to illustrate the path does not get destroyed
\pgfkeys{tikz/.cd,
set edge options/.code={\tikzset{edge style/.style={#1}}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every edge/.append code = {% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396092/121799 
    \global\let\currenttarget\tikztotarget % save \tikztotarget in a global variable
    \pgfkeysalso{append after command={to[edge style] (\currenttarget)}}},
every edge/.append style={edge style}   ] 
\path[name path=A,fill=blue!20] (0.25,0)  
[set edge options={in=-120,out=50}]  edge[ultra thick] (0.75,1.2) 
[set edge options={in=-140,out=60}] edge[ultra thick,blue]  (1.25,1.5) 
[set edge options={in=70,out=50}] edge[ultra thick,red,dashed]  (1.75,0.7) 
-- (2.25,0.1) 
[set edge options={bend left=20}] edge[purple,dotted,thick] (2.75,-0.5) 
[set edge options={bend left=20}] edge[purple,dashed,thick] cycle;
\draw[name path=B] (3,0) to[bend right=16] (0,1);
\fill[yellow,name intersections={of=A and B}] (intersection-1) circle(2pt)
(intersection-2) circle(2pt);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

All you need to is to say in a path

```
(<point n>) [edge options={<path options>}] edge[<visual>] (<point n+1>)
```

Here the path options are those that you normally would feed into a `to[...]` of a path like `in=...,out=...,looseness=...` or `bend left=...`, say. The visual things are those that affect the style of the curve such as color, `dashed`, thickness etc. In particular, these are the things that you normally can *not* change along the path.

Note that the `intersections` library is only loaded for illustration, the syntax proposed here does not rely on it.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**: Just noticed that you do not have to separate the `<path options>` from the `<visual>` ones. Ti*k*Z is clever enough to just ignore the directives if they do not apply. So you can simplify things further to

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone} 
\pgfkeys{tikz/.cd,
edge options/.code={\tikzset{edge style/.style={#1}}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every edge/.append code = {% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396092/121799 
    \global\let\currenttarget\tikztotarget % save \tikztotarget in a global variable
    \pgfkeysalso{append after command={to[edge style] (\currenttarget)}}},
every edge/.append style={edge style}   ] 
\path[fill=blue!20] (0.25,0)  
[edge options={in=-120,out=50,ultra thick,black,-latex}] edge (0.75,1.2) 
[edge options={in=-140,out=60,ultra thick,blue,latex-}] edge   (1.25,1.5) 
[edge options={in=70,out=50,ultra thick,red,dashed}] edge  (1.75,0.7) 
-- (2.25,0.1) 
[edge options={bend left=20,purple,dotted,thick}] edge (2.75,-0.5) 
[edge options={bend left=20,purple,dashed,thick}] edge cycle;
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]