# Conditional line style when plotting curve with PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

I want to plot a function with different styles according to the domain. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            scale only axis=true,
            height=2.8cm,
            width=16cm,
            axis lines=middle,
            xmin=-11,
            xmax=11,
            ymax=1.15,
            ymin=-1.15,
            xtick={-3*pi,-2*pi,-pi,pi,2*pi,3*pi},
            xticklabels={$-3\pi$,$-2\pi$,$-\pi$,$\pi$,$2\pi$,$3\pi$},
            ytick distance=1,
            legend style={
                at={(0.5,1.14)},
                anchor=south,
                legend columns=-1
            },
        ]
            \addplot[domain=-pi/2:pi/2,samples=50,red] {sin(deg(x))};
            \addplot[domain=-3*pi:-pi/2,samples=50,red,dashed] {sin(deg(x))};
            \addplot[domain=pi/2:3*pi,samples=50,red,dashed] {sin(deg(x))};
            \addplot[domain=0:pi,samples=50,blue] {cos(deg(x))};
            \addplot[domain=-3*pi:0,samples=50,blue,dashed] {cos(deg(x))};
            \addplot[domain=pi/2:3*pi,samples=50,blue,dashed] {cos(deg(x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This plots both the sine and the cosine, with a solid line in certain domains, and dashed elsewhere. Is there a way to do this in a single command with PGFPlots? There are certainly [ways](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446013/curved-line-with-varying-style) [to do it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51546/tikz-multi-segment-line-of-varying-thickness?noredirect=1&lq=1) with 'pure' TikZ, but I want to accomplish this specifically with PGFPlots. Thanks!

[image: Output]