# Tikz draw contour without some edges, and fill

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to draw two wave-shaped contours, as in the figure below, and fill the area between. I tried the following code, but it produces an undesired black vertical edge on the right. How do I remove that?

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (-1,-1) rectangle (6,2);
  \draw[fill=black!10] (0,1) to[out=0,in=180] ++(5,-0.6) -- ++(0,0.6) to[out=180,in=0] ++(-5,-0.6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also tried to remove the `--` between `++(5,-0.6)` and `++(0,0.6)` in the 5th line, it doesn't draw the undesired edge, but it messes up the filling.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \useasboundingbox (-1,-1) rectangle (6,2);
   \draw[fill=black!10] (0,1) to[out=0,in=180] ++(5,-0.6) ++(0,0.6) to[out=180,in=0] ++(-5,-0.6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick and dirty: fill the area first and then draw what you want to draw. It is not easily possible to switch off the drawing of a part of a path (but it is possible yet considerably more effort).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (-1,-1) rectangle (6,2);
  \path[fill=black!10] (0,1) to[out=0,in=180] ++(5,-0.6) -- ++(0,0.6) to[out=180,in=0] ++(-5,-0.6);
  \draw (0,1) to[out=0,in=180] ++(5,-0.6)++(0,0.6) to[out=180,in=0] ++(-5,-0.6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You *can* switch the path on and off [e.g. using this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446026/121799).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\pgfkeys{tikz/.cd,
edge options/.code={\tikzset{edge style/.style={#1}}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every edge/.append code = {% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396092/121799 
    \global\let\currenttarget\tikztotarget % save \tikztotarget in a global variable
    \pgfkeysalso{append after command={to[edge style] (\currenttarget)}}},
every edge/.append style={edge style}   ] 
  \useasboundingbox (-1,-1) rectangle (6,2);
  \path[fill=black!10] 
  (0,1) [edge options={out=0,in=180,draw=black}]  edge  ++(5,-0.6) 
  -- ++(0,0.6) 
  [edge options={out=180,in=0,draw=black}] edge ++(-5,-0.6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

With use TikZ library `pgfplots.fillbetween`

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.fillbetween}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[name path=A]  (0, 0.3) to [out=0,in=180] ++(5,-0.6);
\draw[name path=B]  (0,-0.3) to [out=0,in=180] ++(5, 0.6);
\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B] {fill=gray!30};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For comparison, with plain [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), where filling and drawing are kept separate, and where you can concatenate path variables directly.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    z0 = (-72, 8.5);

    path A, B;
    A = z0 {right} .. {right} z0 rotated 180;
    B = A reflectedabout(up, down);

    fill A -- B -- cycle withcolor 7/8[blue, white];
    draw A;
    draw B;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

(compile with `lualatex`...)

[image]